# How can I transfer data from php back to HTML?

Tags: php

My site reads all files in a directory using `glob();` statement in php. I want to use those files' names as a source for images to be displayed as

`<img src="Here I want those file names from php">`

I am a beginner and I hope if anyone can help me for this.

Comment: Have you done any research on how to change a DOM element attribute? What have you found?

Comment: I have a hard time with this downvoting on absolute beginners...

Comment: Yeah, on learning basic too becomes a difficult one @user247245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$files = glob();

<img src="$files[0]" />
<img src="$files[1]" />
```

You can use forloop to show all images.

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){ ?>
<img src="<?php echo $files[$i] ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: <?php
$file = glob("uploaded_music/try these/*");
for ($i=0; $i < count($file); $i++) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $file[$i]; ?>">
<?php}?>
And this returned an error.

Comment: @Pramesh : Paste your code with error into question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I got a solution.
Keeping ":" instead of "{" and in the last php code, ending with "endfor" instead of "}" works.